# Ошибка при регистрации приложения в Telegram

Tags: telegram

Согласно инструкции, зашел на https://my.telegram.org, авторизовался, затем перешел к странице создания нового приложения и при заполнении формы возникает ошибка: **ERROR**

Если заполнить только **App title**, тогда возникает ошибка "**Incorrect app name!**".

Если ввести затем **Short name**, то появляется ошибка с текстом "**ERROR**".

На английском SO нашел только не отвеченный [вопрос от 29 июня](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104560/create-new-application-telegram-api).

Кто сталкивался с подобным? 
Как заполнить поле **URL**? Ввожу туда произвольные адреса - ошибка не исчезает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обращаться напрямую в поддержку Telegram пробовали? Отвечают не всегда сразу, но тем не менее.
Настройки ---> Задать вопрос
Settings  ---> Ask a Question

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал о тех. поддержке, но на их сайте есть инструкция из нескольких пунктов как задать вопрос - там много букв - не осилил). Вы показали более простое решение как к ним обратиться. Если поможет, то отмечу ваш ответ как решение.

Comment: Сегодня попробовал снова - приложение зарегистрировалось без ошибок. Видимо, проблема была на их стороне. Засчитал ваш ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка на самом деле про Short name. Там не должно быть ничего кроме букв или цифр. Даже `_` недопустимо

Answer (score 1):

У меня была эта проблема,когда пытался зарегистрировать приложение через yandex-browser. После попробовал создать через chrome, все создалось за раз.

Answer (score 0):

Пропиши три разных текста в App title, Short name, Description тогда должно работать. У меня такая ошибка появлялась когда были одинаковые значения

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/760661)

Answer (score 0):

У меня проблема такая же была при включеном VPN. Отключил и все заработало